# C++ problems in vector usage

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

Let's say I input values between 0-109 several times. I have a vector that counts how many times a value in a specific range(0-9, 10-19,...100-109) has occurred.

For instance, my vector initially:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I give 15, 16, 88, 95, 94, 5 as input.Vector becomes:

1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector; using std::endl;
using std::cin; using std::cout;

int main()
{
   int m=0;
   vector<int>vec(11,0);//00000000000

   while(cin>>m)
   {
       vec[m/10]=vec[m/10]+1;//ex: m=15->m/10==1->vec[1]=vec[1]+1->vec[1]==1;
   }//use ctrl+z(windows) to break

   cout<<"012345678910"<<endl;

   for(decltype(vec.size()) i:vec)
   {
       cout<<vec[i];
   }
}
```

Why my code doesn't work correctly?

P.S. Code tends to use one value for many elements of vector.

Comment: that's a very poor use of decltype, use `for (auto i: vec)` or many other alternatives

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a much better container for this use case, where you would store the ranges as the `key_type` and the no. of occurrences as `mapped_type`.

Comment: I am learning C++, I tried to make a solution to given problem with tools that I have already learned(haven't learned std::map yet), but it doesn't work. My question is not about how to implement the task, but about what is wrong with my implementation

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury IMHO map is not necessary here. You have here well known indexes: 0-10. Vector is ok, but `std::array<size_t>` would be better.
@UserRR did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not want you expect:

```
for(decltype(vec.size()) i:vec)
   {
       cout<<vec[i];
   }
```

A range based for gives you element values, not element indices.

You likely want:

```
for(const auto& e : vec)
   {
       cout<<e;
   }
```

Comment: If input is 4, 5, 15. then 00000000000->21000000000. So, i need values, not indices I guess

Comment: Oh, I get it now, let me check.